# OptimisticLockException While deleting EBeans in Play 2 Framework

Tags: java, orm, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am trying to delete an object from a list of an other object. But I'm stuck with a strange Exception. I have tryed multiple thing but here is my final test :

```
public static Result unpair(String tokenString)
    {
        Token token = Token.getToken(tokenString);
        if(token == null) return ok(toJson(Error.AUTH_ERROR));

        String epc = form(UnpairRequest.class).bindFromRequest().get().epc;

        //Here the line throwing an Exception
        CommitItem.find().where()
                    .eq("commit.user", token.user)
                    .eq("epc",epc)
                    .findUnique().delete();

        return ok(toJson(Response.OK));
    }
```

It raise this exception :

```
OptimisticLockException: Data has changed. updated [0] rows sql[delete from commit_item where epc=? and evat_price=? and ivat_price=? and vat=? and product_product_code=? and commit_id=?] bind[null]
```

It seems that the Lock is not released after the Select statement but I have no Idea why...

I have also try to delete my object this way :

```
PairingCommit commit = PairingCommit.find().where()
          .eq("user", token.user).findUnique();
CommitItem item = CommitItem.find().where()
          .eq("commit", commit)
          .eq("epc", epc);
commit.items.remove(item);
commit.update();
```

But it doesn't delete my item from the database.
I don't really understand what is going wrong with my code.

Comment: See http://www.avaje.org/occ.html. Basically if you don't specify a version field, Ebean will use all the fields to check if the row was changed between the select (`findUnique`) and the delete

Comment: @Salem Yes but in my case my case the row has not changed between the select and the delete. So I don't understand what is the problem... And why removing item from the list and then update the commit don't do anything ?

Comment: @Salem Ok your link was Really interesting :-) I have find why my All Column check fail... It's because item contains float field, and for mysql 13.37 is not equal to 13.37... How can I solve this ?

Comment: @Salem Ok I have resolved my problem. I have only passed the Mysql type to DECIMAL and it works fine. If you can post it as response, i will mark it as solved.